# How can I remove eclipse completely?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have removed the .eclipse folder, .p2 and the eclipse folder from user->local. But somehow when I am running eclipse its creating a workspace folder at the predefined location which I defined during first use. Do I also have to remove the gradle folder or How can I remove it completely it's so annoying.

Comment: Create one new workspace, it will freshly create everything.

Comment: I want to reset every setting like uninstalling completely.

Comment: Do u install standalone version or,  . Exe installation  ?

Comment: Is this your home directory? Eclipse always creates these folders in the home directory unless you use the `-user` option to specify a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

Create one fresh work space, then open the workspce  in eclipse it will create the new workspace configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you can start Eclipse even after deleting the `.p2` folder, I conclude that you installed Eclipse as a ZIP package and not via the Eclipse Installer.

The predefined location of the workspace is stored inside the **configuration area** which is by default the **subdirectory `configuration`** of the Eclipse **installation directory**.

The Eclipse Java IDE uses in addition to the directories already mentioned by you, for Maven the `.m2` and for Git the `git` subdirectories of the user directory by default. Additionally installed plug-ins might have used further directories.